# PHP and ACL system to Authorize actions in my app

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, acl

I have a php application that I need to add Authentication system and some sort of an ACL.

for the authentication part I choose oAuth based login systems, I will initially support login via Facebook connect.

once the user is authenticated I would like to grant and deny access rights to various part of the application. I need to have these setting persistance over a database.

can you recommend some ACL classes/frameworks that are lightweight and easy to implement ? if they have some sort of a frontend to edit permission that would save me a bunch of time.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the frontend, you probably could find one, but [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) and [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.introduction.html) can be used independently of anything else in the framework.